# Mailgun : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Unable to open

Tags: php, attachment, mailgun, rackspace

I have used the following code and I have placed these files in the same directory as of the script I am running to send the mail.  The exception continues to be thrown even when I try to give an online link.

I am trying this piece of PHP code in my local host which you can figure out from the error below

```
# Include the Autoloader (see "Libraries" for install instructions)
require 'mail/vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

# Instantiate the client.
$mgClient = new Mailgun('key-secret');
$domain = "mydomain";

    $result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'email',
             'to'      => 'email',
             'bcc'     => 'email',
             'subject' => "Sending Attachment 2",
             'text'    => "Sending Attachment",
             'html'    => "Sending Attachment",
             'attachment-1'=> 'test.xml'
),  array("attachment" => array(
                                    array('filePath'   => '@/file.txt', 
                                          'remoteName' => 'file.txt'),
                                    array('filePath'   => '@/test.txt', 
                                          'remoteName' => 'test.txt'))));
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Guzzle\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message
>   'Unable to open /file.txt for reading' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zendeskapis\mail\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Message\PostFile.php:53
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zendeskapis\mail\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Message\PostFile.php(28):
>   Guzzle\Http\Message\PostFile->setFilename('@/file.txt') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zendeskapis\mail\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest.php(199):
>   Guzzle\Http\Message\PostFile->__construct('attachment', '@/file.txt',
>   NULL, 'file.txt') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zendeskapis\mail\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Connection\RestClient.php(52):
>   Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest->addPostFile('attachment',
>   '@/file.txt', NULL, 'file.txt') #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zendeskapis\mail\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\src\Mailgun\Mailgun.php(80):
>   Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->post('hotelpalmshore....', Array,
>   Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\zendeskapis\mail\vendor\mailgun\mailgun-php\
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zendeskapis\mail\vendor\guzzle\guzzle\src\Guzzle\Http\Message\PostFile.php
>   on line 53

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception state it, your file path doesn't seem to be correct.

Assuming you're on a nix system, your **file.txt** should be right under **/** which seems quite unlikely to me.

If you're on a windows system the path `/file.txt` does not have any meaning.

Try to hardcode first your path, once it will work set it dynamically